# T-type flip flop based on SR without additional gates?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, flipflop

I have a question that keeps bugging me. I know how to make a T-type flipflop from SR flipflop by using 2 additional AND gates, but I was wondering, if it is possible to create T-type from SR without additional gates? If so, how to minimize Karnaugh tables to reach such functions?

Comment: No one uses T flip-flops in real design...why does this keep bugging you? Sounds like a homework question to me. Please show all of the work you have done to try to solve this on your own, and then ask a specific question.

Comment: Well, I'm learning about these right now and it just caught my interest.

Comment: You'll learn a lot more if you know how to search with the best key words https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=+T-type++SR+flipflop

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Well, I did search with the very same keywords, yet did not found a single thread with answer to my question.

Comment: It depends on your ability to search.  You need the extra gates for edge detection for any FF which cannot be done with any simple SR async latch.  Sync=Clk vs. async.=RS  http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~ehwang/courses/cs120b/flipflops.pdf  If it fails at first use different key words and try a better search engine